# How to change image of cell?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have custom cell in iPhone which have which have a button and image view i want to change the image of image view when i clicked on the button here is my button code

```
-(void)btnLikePressed:(UIButton *)sender{

     imageDC *objMenu = [dataArray objectAtIndex:sender.tag];
    GET_DBHANDLER
    [dbHandler performSelector:@selector(like_image:) withObject: objMenu.image_id];


}
```

Comment: What does that `performSelector:withObject:` serve for? Why not simply `[dbHandler like_image:objMenu.image_id]`? Also, the naming convention in Objective-C goes like this: method and variable names use camelCaps. `[dbHandler likeImage:objMenu.imageID]`.

Answer (score 0):

To your method to find out the exact index of your `UITableViewCell` please use the following :-

```
CGPoint point = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:_iTableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_iTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
```

You will get your **indexpath**. From here you can identify your `UIImageView`, hope you have given tags to them and then change the image.

Answer (score 0):

Following steps will work:-

1. tag your imageview.
2. use this code in cellForRowatIndexpath

   ```
   NSArray *nib;
   static NSString *cellIdentifier= @"cell";

   UITableViewCell *theCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


   if(theCell== nil)
   {
       {
           nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:<Your cellNibName> owner:self options:nil]; 
       }
       theCell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
       theCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
       // theCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
   }

   UIImageView *imageView=(UIImageView*)[[theCell contentView] viewWithTag:<Your tag>];
   ```

   //do what ever you want with imageView
3. You got image view ref do what you want.

Comment: i have image view on custom cell @amar

Comment: Yes take a seperate .xib for custom cell and load that nib its nothing new we do it on a daily basis very basic.

Comment: take a empty userinterface add a tableview cell to it customize it and tag various components

Answer (score 0):

In UITableViewDataSource function

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

while setting cell just add tag to your button and imageView as well.

```
cell.yourBtn.tag   = indexPath.row;
cell.imageView.tag = indexPath.row + 1000(any number);
```

now in your UITableViewController class

now when user click on the button you get the button tag that is actually your row number and imageView(btn tag + 1000) tag as well that you can get imageView by using same info.

```
 -(void)btnLikePressed:(UIButton *)sender{

    NSInteger btnTag = [sender tag];
    UIImageView *imageView = [yourTableView viewWithTag:btnTag + 1000];
    // here your code by using imageView    
}
```

Comment: how can i access the image view in button click event

Answer (score 0):

try this bellow code

```
-(void)btnLikePressed:(UIButton *)sender{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"yourCellName";

    UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell*)[[sender superview] superview];

    UITableView *tableView=(UITableView*)[cell superview];
    NSIndexPath *path=[tableView indexPathForCell:cell];


    yourCellName *selectedCell = (yourCellName*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    [selectedCell.imageView.image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageName.png"]]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First give tagValue to your imageView , like you gave 5 to your imageView. 
Then access this on buttonClick.

```
-(void)btnLikePressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell*)[sender superview];

    UIImageView*imageView=(UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:5];

    //Now do whatEver you want to do with your imageview
}
```

**EDIT**

If you added your imageView as

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
```

Then get your tableView cell like this

```
UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell*)[[sender superview] superview];
```